# stack smashing in string and infinite loop

Tags: c, string, loops, segmentation-fault

> stack smashing

stuck in loop.
enters an infinite loop randomly.
sometimes during first time sometimes during second.
The code is a mess however. the logic is to split a string into three strings alternatively three times.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char    mstr[21];
void    split(char    str1[21]);
void    printx(char    strxyz[7]);
void    main()
{
    int    i,j,count=0;
    char    str[21];
    for(i=1;i<=21;i++)
    {
        str[i-1]=i;
        printf("%d\t",str[i-1]);
        if(i%7==0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    while(count<3)
    {
        split(str);
        count++;
    }
}
void    split(char    str1[21])
{   
    int    i,j=0,k,ans,n;
    char    strx[7],stry[7],strz[7];
    printf("\n\n*    *    *    *    *    split    *    *    *    *    *\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<21;)
    {
        for(n=0;j<7;n++)
        {
            strx[j]=str1[i];i=i+1;
            stry[j]=str1[i];i=i+1;
            strz[j]=str1[i];i=i+1;
            j=j+1;
        }
    }
    printf("enter    the    group\n");
    scanf("%d",&ans);
    switch(ans)
    {
        case    1:
            strcat(stry,strx);
            strcat(stry,strz);
            strcpy(mstr,stry);
            break;
        case    2:
            strcat(strx,stry);
            strcat(strx,strz);
            strcpy(mstr,strx);
            break;
        case    3:
            strcat(strx,strz);
            strcat(strx,stry);
            strcpy(mstr,strx);
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid\n");
    }
printf("\n mstr values\n");
for(k=0;k<21;k++)
{
    printf("%d\t",mstr[k]);
}

}

void    printx(char    strxyz[7])
{
    int    i;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",strxyz[i]);
    }
}
```

**2nd Output:**

student@CSE-LAB3:~/Desktop/fdrive$ cc shuffle.c
student@CSE-LAB3:~/Desktop/fdrive$ ./a.out

1   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19  20  21

- - - - - split    *    *    *    *    *

enter    the    group
2

mstr values
1   4   7   10  13  16  19  2   5   8   11  14  17  20  3   6   9   12  15  18  21

- - - - - split    *    *    *    *    *

enter    the    group
2

mstr values
1   4   7   10  13  16  19  2   5   8   11  14  17  20  3   6   2   5   8   11  14

- - - - - split    *    *    *    *    *

enter    the    group
1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

> edited:

```
the string 

str = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21

now we have to split the string into three. 
so.
strx = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
stry = 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
srtrz = 15 16 17 18 19 20 21

now based on the input (1 or 2 or 3 ) merge the string into a single string.
if the input is 1. place the string strx( first sub string ) in the middle. so it becomes 
like stry+strx+strz

> output
> 1 4 7 10 13 16 19
> 2 5 8 11 14 17 20
> 3 6 9 12 15 18 21
```

> logic:
>   Imagine a real life problem.You have 21 cards. You divide it into three stacks of 7 cards. You ask your friend to think of a card from the three stacks.You then ask which stack has the card. The stack that contains the card is placed in the middle of other two stacks and merged without changing the order. Now You have to split the stack of 21 cards into 7 cards stacks . The process is repeated 3 times i.e. he has to choose the stack 3 times.

Comment: Can you show an example input and expected output for this. Difficult for us to help if we don't even know what your trying to do.

Comment: see if you can understand now.  @RoadRunner

Comment: how is your output supposed to make sense with your explanation stry + strx + strz My understanding is 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 1 2 3 ... 7 15 16 17 .. 21, you need to provide more detail about merging rules

Comment: Segmantation fault means you try to write a memory location you are not supposed to. That means you have some problems with your array indexes. Try to run it through gdb or visual studio debugger. They are really helpful.

Comment: See the logic section . Try if you can understand it. @nomadov

Comment: You are almost right .  you have to place the card in the same way you said . Then you have to split it into three. Do you get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of fundamental problems. The worst is that you are not terminating your strings with `'\0'` characters. This leads to undefined behavior. Also, you are concatenating, for example, `strx` to `stry`. But there is no room in the character array `strx[]` to hold the additional characters.

You can fix these problems by changing all declarations for arrays of size `21` to `22`, e.g., `char mstr[22];`, and changing all declarations for arrays of size `7` to `8`, e.g., `char strx[8];`. Then you need to be sure to add `NUL` terminators to the end of each string. One way to accomplish this would be to zero-initialize each of the arrays. Another method is to explicitly add the `NUL` character, and this is what I have done in the code below.

Then, you need to change the code that combines the strings. This code should copy the first substring into `mstr[]`, and then concatenate the next two substrings:

```
case    1:
        strcpy(mstr,stry);
        strcat(mstr,strx);
        strcat(mstr,strz);
```

There is also a significant logic error in the code that splits the strings. The double loop that you have is going out of array bounds. Consider that when `i` reaches `20`, you will have: `strz[j]=str1[22];i=22+1;`, since `i` has already been incremented twice. This should be simplified to:

```
for(i=0, j=0; j < 7; j++, i += 3)
{
    strx[j] = str1[i];
    stry[j] = str1[i + 1];
    strz[j] = str1[i + 2];
}
strx[j] = '\0';
stry[j] = '\0';
strz[j] = '\0';
```

It sounds like you want to preserve the changes made during each call to `split()`, so you should remove `str[]` from `main()` and instead use the global `mstr[]` here, since this is the string that you are storing the shuffled results in. It would be much better to remove the global entirely, though, as it is best to only use globals when you *have* to. Since the `split()` function distributes the contents of `str1` among each of the strings `strx`, `stry`, and `strz`, you can store the combined results back in `str1`. And since `str1` is a pointer to the first element of `mstr[]`, the change is visible in the calling function. To accomplish this, the declaration for `mstr[]` needs to be moved into `main()`, and the code to combine strings should look like:

```
case    1:
    strcpy(str1,stry);
    strcat(str1,strx);
    strcat(str1,strz);
```

Here is modified code that does more or less what I think you intended. I also added some code to print the resulting array after three calls to `split()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void    split(char    str1[22]);
void    printx(char    strxyz[8]);

int main(void)
{
    int    i,count=0;
    char    mstr[22];

    for(i=0;i<21;i++)
    {
        mstr[i]=i+1;
        printf("%d\t",mstr[i]);
        if((i+1)%7==0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    mstr[i] = '\0';

    while(count<3)
    {
        split(mstr);
        count++;
    }

    printf("\nResults:\n");
    for(i=0;i<21;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",mstr[i]);
        if((i+1)%7==0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void    split(char    str1[22])
{   
    int    i,j,k,ans;
    char    strx[8],stry[8],strz[8];
    printf("\n\n*    *    *    *    *    split    *    *    *    *    *\n\n");

    for(i=0, j=0;j<7;j++, i+=3)
    {
        strx[j]=str1[i];
        stry[j]=str1[i+1];
        strz[j]=str1[i+2];
    }
    strx[j] = '\0';
    stry[j] = '\0';
    strz[j] = '\0';

    printf("enter    the    group\n");
    scanf("%d",&ans);
    switch(ans)
    {
    case    1:
        strcpy(str1,stry);
        strcat(str1,strx);
        strcat(str1,strz);

        break;
    case    2:
        strcpy(str1,strx);
        strcat(str1,stry);
        strcat(str1,strz);

        break;
    case    3:
        strcpy(str1,strx);
        strcat(str1,strz);
        strcat(str1,stry);

        break;
    default:
        printf("invalid\n");
    }
    printf("\n str1 values\n");
    for(k=0;k<21;k++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",str1[k]);
    }
}

void    printx(char    strxyz[8])
{
    int    i;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",strxyz[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to split the string into three sub strings alternatively

Comment: No actually in my code im splitting alternatively . Haven't you seen the Logic?

Comment: see this. s1=1,2,3 s2=4,5,6 s3=7,8,9. selecting s2. str=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 now splitting. s1=1,4,7 s2=2,5,8 s3=3,6,9

Answer (score 0):

In procedure split, you have `j<=7` but it should be `j<7` or `j<=6` to prevent **out of bound** problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still i have logic problem

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds to me is there may be an uninitialized value or a wrong condition for terminating the loop.

I've spotted a problem, for example in the function,

```
void    split(char str1[21])
{   
    //i, k and n are later initialized but j is not.
    int i,j,k,ans,n;
    char strx[7],stry[7],strz[7];
    printf("\n\n*    *    *    *    *    split    *    *    *    *    *\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<21;)
    {
        //j is not initialized, how do you know compiler will initialize it to 0 for sure?
        //j <= 7 should be j < 7
        for(n=0;j<=7;n++)
        {
            strx[j]=str1[i];i=i+1;
            stry[j]=str1[i];i=i+1;
            strz[j]=str1[i];i=i+1;
            j=j+1;
        }
     }

     printf("enter the group\n");

     scanf("%d",&ans);

     switch(ans)
     {
        case 1:
             strcat(stry,strx);
             strcat(stry,strz);
             strcpy(mstr,stry);
             break;
         case 2:
             strcat(strx,stry);
             strcat(strx,strz);
             strcpy(mstr,strx);
             break;
         case 3:
             strcat(strx,strz);
             strcat(strx,stry);
             strcpy(mstr,strx);
             break;
         default:
             printf("invalid\n");
}

    printf("\n mstr values\n");

    for(k=0;k<21;k++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",mstr[k]);
    }
}
```

You declare j without initialization then it is compared against 7 in the for loop where n is incremented. Each time the program is started, they may be initialized to a random value. That's why you might receive undefined behavior. Also `j <= 7` should be `j < 7`

Comment: You are right . It caused the loop problem. Now  there are logic errors can You help?

Comment: You need to change the way you code. For example never declare a variable that is uninitialized or don't declare a variable you won't use. Don't declare all variables beforehand but declare them as you need. Also make sure loops are terminated under right conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @nomadov

Comment: the string is not splitting as expected

Comment: One more thing I realized is you are assigning int values to an char array. You can't simply do that. You can't for example do char x [2] = 2; Assigned value has to be an ASCII value. That's why probably you're getting an segmentation fault because a char is 1 byte whereas an int is 4 bytes. Last index of a char array has a space for 1 byte when you write 4 bytes, it exceeds the given space thereby may cause seg faults.